# Not sure how to program this class with the test case

Tags: java, function, testing, methods, junit

I have the test case for this class and I must fill in all of the methods. I've gotten some of the last ones that are simply returning things that have already been created. But I am not sure how to do the rest of the methods. Any tips? We are creating a game of Yahtzee.

Here is the class where I must fill in the methods

```
import java.util.Vector;
import model.Player;

public class YahtzeeEngine {
    public static final int MAX_ROLLS = 0;
    private Vector<Player> myPlayers;
    private Roller myRoller;
    private Player myPlayerUp;
    private int myNumberRollsUsed;
    public Vector myPlayer;

    public YahtzeeEngine(int numPlayers) {
    }

    public void startGame() {
    }

    public void selectPlayerUp(Player player) {
    }

    public void switchPlayerUp() {
    }

    public boolean incrementRollsUsed() {
        return false;
    }

    public void resetNumberRollsUsed() {
        myNumberRollsUsed = 0;
    }

    public Roller getRoller() {
        return myRoller;
    }

    public Player getPlayerUp() {
        return myPlayerUp;
    }

    public Vector<Player> getPlayers() {
        return myPlayers;
    }

    public int getNumberRollsUsed() {
        return myNumberRollsUsed;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the completed test class for it

```
package yahtzee.testing;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import yahtzee.model.Player;
import yahtzee.model.Roller;
import yahtzee.model.YahtzeeEngine;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * This class is built to test the methods within the YahtzeeEngine class.
 * Each test case should pass if the code is properly implemented.
 */
public class TestYahtzeeEngine {
    /**
     * Tests that the Category keeps track of the proper
     * amount of rolls that have been used.
     */
    @Test
    public void testIncrement() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ye.incrementRollsUsed();
        }

        assertTrue(ye.getNumberRollsUsed() == 3);
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the number of rolls is reset to zero when resetRolls() has been called.
     */
    @Test
    public void testResetRolls() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ye.incrementRollsUsed();
        }

        ye.resetNumberRollsUsed();

        assertTrue(ye.getNumberRollsUsed() == 0);
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the current player up will rotate properly
     * when the switchPlayerUp() method is invoked.
     */
    @Test
    public void testPlayerUp() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(2);
        Player player1 = ye.getPlayers().get(0);

        ye.selectPlayerUp(player1);
        ye.switchPlayerUp();

        assertFalse(ye.getPlayerUp().equals(player1));
    }   

    /**
     * Tests if the player vector is the correct length for min number of players.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMinPlayerVector() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(1);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().size() == 1);
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the player vector is the correct length for max number of players.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMaxPlayerVector() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(6);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().size() == 6);
    }

    /**
     * Test that bad number of players passed in defaults to 2 players.
     */
    @Test
    public void testTooFewPlayerVector1() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(0);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().size() == 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTooFewPlayerVector2() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(7);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().size() == 2);
    }

    /**
     * Tests that the game is properly instantiated after startGame() has been called.
     */
    @Test
    public void testStartOfGame() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(2);
        ye.startGame();

        assertTrue(ye.getNumberRollsUsed() == 0);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayerUp() != null);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().get(0) != null);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().get(1) != null);
        assertTrue(ye.getRoller() != null);
    }

    /**
     * Testing values from YahtzeeEngine on default construction.
     */
    @Test
    public void testYahtzeeEngineConstructor() {
        YahtzeeEngine ye = new YahtzeeEngine(1);

        assertTrue(ye.getNumberRollsUsed() == 0);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayerUp() == null);
        assertTrue(ye.getRoller() == null);
        assertTrue(ye.getPlayers().size() == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any specific problems :)

Comment: you're basically asking us for tips on all the functions to implement. Be more specific in your question and you'll increase your chances of getting a meaningful answer!

Comment: Well I've done the 5 above the toString() where they just return something. But I am not sure how to program the methods above those, not sure how to do so based on what the test case has. For example, in the public boolean method, how do I know what to do?

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is fill in the blanks for the methods...

Comment: @Farlan, right but how am I supposed to know what to put in them?

Comment: In order to write programs, you first need to know what you want them to accomplish and how that will work logically. The code comes last. **For example:** Accomplish: compute radius from area, Logic: sq. root of area divided by pi, Code: Return Math.Sqrt((area / Math.PI))

Comment: It loooks like a homework, but Stackoverflow is not a Do-My-Homework-As-A-Service ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The method "toString()" i would use to return the values in a formatted way.
For example if your class would have the floats X, Y, Z i would return ("X="+X+" Y="+Y+" Z="+Z)

Inside startGame() i would create a Thread which runs the game loop:

```
public void startGame() {
    Thread game = new Thread(this);
    game.start();
}

public void stopGame() {
    System.exit(1);
}

public void run() {
    while (run) {
    // TODO your game
    }
    // terminate
    stopGame();
}
```

You have to implement Runnable for this, because else you can't give the 'this' to the Thread constructor.
The variable run is a boolean which indicates that your game is still running so if you set it to `false` your game will stop.